# how to set include directory for rebar

Tags: erlang, rebar

In my module I have

```
-include("blah.hrl").
```

The `.hrl` file is not in the module's directory, but somewhere else on my system. How can I make `rebar` find it when compiling? Is there a way to add a path to the include directory in `rebar.config`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
{erl_opts, [{i, PathToIncludeFile}]}.
```

in rebar.config should do the thing. Or append {i, ...} to the existing erl_opts, if you have any.